# Is a there a Coder Product (Embedded, Simulink,or Matlab) which supports version 2010SP1

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-compiler, matlab-coder

I am looking for a product which will convert my Matlab code into C++ code. I have looked into Matlab Coder extensively but it seems that it will not suffice as it is only compatible with versions of Matlab from 2011a on wards. I was going to look into the other coder products (Embedded/Simulink) but they both list Matlab Coder as a requirement.

I have Matlab Compiler but I was looking for a product which will fully convert my code and allow it to be run without any Matlab/MCR dependencies.

Is there a Matlab or third party product other there that will convert my code to C++ or will I just need to hand code it over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, MATLAB Coder was released in R2011a. Prior to that, you could still generate C code from (a subset of) MATLAB that will run without any MCR dependencies, using "Embedded MATLAB" (the function of interest was called `emlc` if my memory serves me well). However, this required a product called Real-Time Workshop, which in turn required Simulink. So to generate C code from MATLAB, you needed to have Simulink, even if you were not using Simulink. I guess that's why they introduced MATLAB Coder in R2011a. If you intend to generate production-quality code, for example to run on an embedded device, where you can customise and optimise the generated code, I would strongly recommend Real-Time Workshop Embedded Coder, which is an add-on to Real-Time Workshop.

The bottom line is that yes it's possible, but it will cost you... $$$ £££

Comment: All of that checks out with what I have been reading and fills in the what I could not find, Thanks for the quick answer! My follow question would be Can you still purchase Real-Time Workshop nowadays but I think that is a question best fit for a Matlab Rep!